# How to change the current selection in a wxListbook from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, wxwidgets

How can I change the current selection in a wxListbook from another thread?

When I pass the listbook's pointer to the thread and try to change the selection, the app crashes. What is a safe way of doing this? Is there some message I can send to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should avoid accessing wxWidget objects outside the main thread. [wxWidgets isn't thread safe.](http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/feature2.htm) What you can do is [sending an event to the main thread.](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication) So you do your work in your own thread but do the updating of `wxListbook` inside the main thread.